# Why can't I see individual email accounts anymore after update to iOS 7.1?

Tags: ios, ipad, mail.app, email

After upgrade to iOS7 on my iPad, I cannot see my individual email accounts anymore. The overview of accounts only shows "All" as an inbox. See this screenshot:

[image]

I've actually got two different email accounts on that iPad, and before the upgrade, they were showing. The settings still show them, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Mail app and click EDIT in the top right corner...

You will see the screen that posted below.

Simply check the circles next to the email addresses for which you want to see separate in-boxes, then click DONE and back out of the screen.

[image: inboxes]

Das is ales, as solte nun arbeiten